# Issues in Implementing Facebook Share API on my web application

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, facebook, web

I'm currently trying to figure how I can implement the Facebook Share API on my application. I have been getting errors even though I have implemented it correctly. Here is so far what I've done. I have copied the following code below from the Facebook Application that I have just created and placed it on the Web Application that I'm currently building.

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'APP ID',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.9'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


  $('#facebook').on('click', function() {

      // FB.ui({
      //   method: 'feed',
      //   link: 'http://localhost/es/',
      //   caption: 'An example caption',
      // }, function(response){});

      FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        display: 'popup',
        quote: 'test',
        href: 'http://nytimes.com/'
      }, function(response){});
  })
```

I tried testing it and right now I got this error.

[image]

This is the web application that I'm currently developing and is running on Python/Angular.

I made a separate page on my localhost using XAMPP and also using the same Facebook Code for testing. And to my surprise it works.

[image]

If you look at the settings on my Facebook Application. I did not have to add the url in `App Domains` and also `Site URL` in order for it work (Look at the second image). I tried placing the IP address of my Web App but it won't allow it. I even disabled the pop-up blocker that is installed on my browser

[image]

Comment: What do you mean, _“I did not have to add the url in App Domains and also Site URL”_ - the error message is telling you that you need to do that.

Comment: And sharing from localhost doesn’t make much sense - Facebook needs to be able to read the URL to extract the Open Graph meta data from it.

Comment: @CBroe Look at the Second Image. It clearly shows the Share Dialog Box working even without having to place the url in the `App Domains` and `Site URL`

Comment: And I cannot use an IP Address for the URL inside the App Domains and Site URL. Facebook won't allow it

Comment: _“Look at the Second Image”_ - look at the error message ...

Comment: I know that but it is a form of an IP address, are there any alternatives in order for it to make it work. Some of the answers I have seen in SO doesn't require the `App Domains` and `Site URL` value to be fullfilled

Comment: No, Facebook does not play well with IP addresses in general. // It might be that they have an exception for `localhost`, so that you can use the SDK under that without specifying a domain. But for pretty much anything else, you need to specify an app domain.

Comment: @CBroe Is there an alternative instead of using Facebook share API?

Comment: If you want to test locally, then set up a local test domain.